# Regex: At least 2 symbols or numbers (or mixed) in Java

Tags: java, regex

I know these questions are lame and make Stack Overflow like a regex dictionary, but I really would need some help with. It's like trying to understand hieroglyphs (at least for someone this is easy reputation).

I want to write a regex to check if password is at least 8 characters long and has at least 2 numbers or symbols (or mixed). The symbols probably can be the obvious ones `[-+_!@#$%^&*.,?]`.

So I've come up with something like this so far: `^(?=.{8,})(?=.*\d{2,}).*$`, but I can't understand how to put the symbols sequence in the `\d` part. Oh, I'm not sure if (?=) does work for Java, does it? This [rubular.com/r/VC0ncbDlRl](http://www.rubular.com/r/VC0ncbDlRl) made writing regex little easier.

Comment: Why not making first a string length check (for 8 chars) and then one regex for numbers and another for symbols? Regexes are not a good fit for this kind of problems, where characters can be anywhere.

Comment: @Pablo Uh, what are regexes good for then?

Comment: @Richards: For soooo much. When you learn working with it you will see it is really amazing. RegEx's are used to find/check regular data, like ip-addresses, email addresses, etc... Take a look at this site: http://www.regular-expressions.info/examples.html

Comment: @Martijn, I see.. this just seemed perfect case (for me) to use regex too. Common pitfall?

Comment: @Richards, for things like "this followed by that, and optionally by this and that". Check @Martijn answer. The code is readable, and you don't need to know stuff like positive lookahead (that your regex uses). Your teammates (and yourself in a few months) will be happier if you go that way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is not a job to do with a RegEx. In Java, it is so much simpler to write some custom code:

```
public static boolean isValidPassword(String pass)
{
    if (pass.length() < 8) return false;

    int symbolOrNumberCount = 0;
    String symbols = "0123456789-+_!@#$%^&*.,?";

    for (int i = 0; i < pass.length(); ++i)
    {
        if (symbols.indexOf((int) pass.charAt(i)) != -1)
        {
            symbolOrNumberCount++;
        }
    }

    return symbolOrNumberCount >= 2;
}
```

Comment: bravo, I was writing the same but in a comment :S

Comment: @Pablo @Martijn: "Simpler"? Compare your code to mine. Which do you consider simpler?

Comment: p.s. I do agree that it's not a great match for regex, but it can be done.

Comment: "Simpler"... Well, my code is almost speakable. It is pure logical. But a regex is so difficult to understand when they are that complex. And, yes I know that regexes are logical as well... :)

Comment: @Ryan Your code is more complex in every way. This is not a code golf competition

Comment: @Ryan also, name your variables properly. `chars`, `sorted` and `pattern` are very poor names.

Comment: @Pablo: My code has a significantly lower cyclomatic complexity than yours, so I can't agree that it's more complex in *every* way. And with the var names, you're just nitpicking. But consider me properly chastised: var names fixed.

Comment: @Ryan the fact that the iteration is happening inside the `Pattern` class instead of you manually creating a for loop does not reduce the complexity of your code, just hides it behind the JDK classes. Also you're mixing levels of abstraction (in only 6 lines of code!) and you already had a bug, again in only 6 LOC. That's a sing your code is an overkill for this problem, and unnecessary  complex

Comment: @Pablo: I completely agree, except for the part about hiding complexity in other classes. That's a great strategy for getting complexity out of your codebase, as I think I've shown in my other answer to this question.

Answer (score 3):

Another way to count numbers and specials that's "simpler" all around, using Commons Collections:

```
int matches = CollectionUtils.countMatches(
    passwordCharacters, new NumberOrSpecialCharacterPredicate());
return passwordCharacters.size() >= 8 && matches >= 2;

class NumberOrSpecialCharacterPredicate implements Predicate {
    private static final String symbols = "0123456789-+_!@#$%^&*.,?";
    public boolean evaluate(Object object) {
        return symbols.indexOf((Character) object) >= 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're missing the `legnth > 8` check

Comment: @Pablo: yeah, I was just going to demo the "special" character counting, but I just updated it to include the overall length check, too.

Comment: Thank you for this alternative, but I don't feel like including another library.

Answer (score 2):

The other answer is a good one, but here's another way:

```
String password = "sn3arki7p";
char[] passwordCharacters = password.toCharArray();
Arrays.sort(passwordCharacters);
String sortedPassword = new String(passwordCharacters);
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(?=.{8,})(?=.*[-+_!@#$%^&*.,?0-9]{2,}).*$");
System.out.println(pattern.matcher(sortedPassword).matches());
```

Edit: Adjusted to require at least 2 of (number or special) instead of 2 number and 2 special.

Comment: I would like the password to contain at least 2 numbers or 2 symbols or 1 number and 1 symbol. Well in sort - at least 2 of this group: `0123456789-+_!@#$%^&*.,?`.

Comment: @Richards: Adjusted the answer's regex to match that.

Comment: Check this: http://www.rubular.com/r/LwO7hSmwhX it matches "snarki7p" too but it has only "7".

Comment: Yeah, sorry. Forgot that the \d outside wouldn't be quantified. Updated.

Comment: @Richards: You should give serious consideration to what @Pablo and @Martijn are saying. There are more maintainable ways to solve your problem than with this moderately complex regex.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
^(?=.{8,})(.*[-+_!@#$%^&*.,?0-9]){2,}
```

Comment: Thank you, with `String.matches("^(?=.{8,})(.*[-+_!@#$%^&*.,?0-9]){2,}")` works perfect!

Comment: @Richards: This is wrong. It doesn't match, for example "abc34def"

Comment: @Richards: I followed the test on rubular and we can clearly see that it doesn't match the string. It only matches a part of it.

Comment: @Richards: You should be doing some fairly rigorous unit testing of your "password validator" in Java and not relying on sporadic, manual testing at a regex website whose behavior you can't even be sure matches Java's.

Comment: This would also work: `^(?=.{8})(.*[-+_!@#$%^&*.,?0-9]){2}`.

It meets the requirements. You _don't_ need to match _all_ of the password.

If the password should be at least 8 characters, you can stop matching when you see the 8th character, and if there should be at least 2 characters from a set, you can stop matching when you see the 2nd character which is from the set.